# Selenium File upload on chrome from android phone

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to upload file in a selenium test that is run on chrome browser on an android phone. The usual `element.sendkeys(path)` is not working. 
Are there any known alternatives for android ?

Comment: send_keys upload won't work if ur using appium for mobile automation

Comment: What is the alternative ?

Comment: u can use pushFile as alternative

Comment: I don't think you get the question, I don't want to upload a file to the phone. I want to test the upload file button on my website with selenium

Comment: then u can pywinauto if ur using python or else AutoIT

Comment: These are scripting languages for windows not android

Answer (score 0):

It may help to upload the file:

```html
public CorePage UploadHack(string fileInputId, string contentType, string fileContent, string fileName, string angularScopeVar)
    {
        UploadFile(_filePath);
        var uploadHack =
            "(function(){" +
                "function convert(base64){" +
                    "var raw = atob(base64);" +
                    "var arr = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(raw.length));" +
                    "for (var i = 0; i < raw.length; i++){" +
                        "arr[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);" +
                    "}" +
                    "return arr; " +
                "}" +
                $"var file = new Blob([convert('{fileContent}')], {{'type':'{contentType}'}}); " +
                $"file.name = '{fileName}'; " +
                $"angular.element('#{fileInputId}').scope().{angularScopeVar} = file;" +
            "})()";
        Driver.ExecuteJavaScript(uploadHack);
        return this;
    }
```